# From which Hindu text the following slokha has been taken?

Tags: karma, shloka

The slokha is

"**Avasyam anubhogthavyam kritham karma subha asubham; naa bhugtham ksheeyathe karma kalpa koti sathairapi**"

Is it from vedas or puranas or any other text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sloka is from Brahmavaivartha Purana. It exist in Prakriti Khanda and at multiple places.

1. First there's verse 71 here: http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/30831/77f_chapter_56_2.pdf
2. Then there's verse 17 of this chapter: http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/30776/77f_chapter_67.pdf

3.Then verse 56 of this chapter: http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/30811/77f_chapter_89_1.pdf

4. Then verse 39 here: http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/30820/77f_chapter_95.pdf

Courtesy: Keshav Srinivasan

Comment: What do you mean 1.44?  What Khanda of the Brahma Vaivarta Purana is it from?  The first, Khanda, the Brahma Khanda, is only 30 chapters long.

Comment: You are right. I copied from my notes, may be I must have made some mistake in my notes. I will have to go back to source then. Plz delete the comment. Thanks.

Comment: In this link- https://archive.org/stream/brahmavaivartapu04allauoft#page/n9/mode/2up The Ganesha Khanda is given at the beginning and it does consist of 44 Khandas. It is possible that the said verse said is in it. I am not in a position to cross check as of now.

Comment: That link is just one volume out of a multi-volume book, and it's not even the first volume of the book.  In any case, the order of the Khandas is Brahma Khanda, Prakriti Khanda, Ganesha Khanda, and Krishna Janma Khanda.  So I doubt chapter 44 of the Ganesha Khanda will lead to anywhere useful.

Comment: In any case, I found four chapters of the Prakriti Khanda which each contain a verse with roughly with roughly the same meaning as the one we're looking for. First there's verse 71 here: http://www.indianscriptures.com/Content/Articles/PDFs/30831/77f_chapter_56_2.pdf  Then there's verse 17 of this chapter: http://www.indianscriptures.com/Content/Articles/PDFs/30776/77f_chapter_67.pdf Then verse 56 of this chapter: http://www.indianscriptures.com/Content/Articles/PDFs/30811/77f_chapter_89_1.pdf Then verse 39 here: http://www.indianscriptures.com/Content/Articles/PDFs/30820/77f_chapter_95.pdf

Comment: I can't read Devanagari script, so I don't know if any of them is the one we're looking for.  Assuming you know Devanagari, please tell me.  By the way, chapter 44 of the Ganesha Purana doesn't have the verse we're looking for: http://www.indianscriptures.com/Content/Articles/PDFs/30900/77f_chapter_141_2.pdf

Comment: Actually all those verses do contain the verses mentioned by the questionnaire. Only that the order has changed- Its written like this- naa bhugtham ksheeyathe karma kalpa koti sathairapi, Avasyam anubhogthavyam kritham karma subha asubham"

Thanks for giving proper reference.

Comment: You're welcome.  You should add that info to your answer.