# Does knowledge has capacity to nullify all past karma?

Tags: krishna, karma

[This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9234/from-which-hindu-text-the-following-slokha-has-been-taken) s**lokha from Brahmavaivartha Purana** says the following

[image]

But **[Geetha chapter 4 verse 37](http://www.bhagavad-gita.org/Gita/verse-04-37.html)** says the following

[image]

First one says that, *no one can escape* from the results of karma, but next says that getting *knowledge can nullify all past karma*.

**Aren't they contradictory**?  How to interpret them properly?

If I am a great sinner and If I get enlightened by getting knowledge, then does the karma again follows after me as per first slokha or I become free from all my past karma as per next slokha?

Comment: Give Bhagavadgita reference in English too, as some people on this site don't speak Telugu. http://www.bhagavad-gita.org/Gita/verse-04-37.html

Comment: See [this](http://sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=686&parent=632&format=html) page for understanding of "Mind" and its concepts.

Comment: There are three ways to nullify past karma. 1. Through Surrender (Lord Krishna says in the Gita that He will Himself destroy all the sins of those who have surrendered to Him). 2. Through Knowledge (Wisdom of your true nature destroys all karma, because karma is a creation of the Mind, which is illusion, thus Knowledge destroys all karma, for the world ceases to be. Then where is the question of actions?). 3. Through selfless service (when you don't have any desires, there is no question of bad karma, nothing matters, for you are happy no matter what you get. This is teachings of Lord Buddha).

Comment: @Sai Then is the first slokha false?

Comment: The first sentence is relatively true. i.e Unless you have attained self-realization or have surrendered to God or have destroyed all moha (all three are just different ways of saying the same thing actually), the law of karma appears to be inescapable and it is the law of the Universe. All the best.

Comment: You can't surrender without knowledge, and without knowledge there is no selfless service. If one thing is missing all things are missing but if you get 1 of the three things there will be present all other.

Answer (score 3):

First I do not see them as contradictory as the verse from the *Brahmavaivartha Purana* you quote is only addressing what happens to a soul who has not attained Self-Realization - it does not address what happens to a soul who attains Self-Realization. The verse from the *Gita*, on the other hand, is addressing what happens to a soul who attains Self-Realization. I think a more appropriate verse from the *Gita* to compare to the *Brahmavaivartha Purana* verse is *Gita* verses 2. 42-45.

If you still insist that the *Gita* and *Brahmavaivartha Purana* are contradictory, then Sruti supports Krishna's statement in the *Gita*, which is not surprising as the *Gita* is the greatest commentary on the *Vedas*. When there is a conflict between Sruti and Smriti or Purana, Sruti takes precedence (Sankara's commentary on *Brahma Sutras* verses 1.2.25, 2.1.1, and others).

And Sruti says - The *Mundaka Upanishad* II. ii. 8 (Swami Nikhilananda translator, both quotes):

> The fetters of the heart are broken, all doubts are resolved, and all works cease to bear fruit, when He is beheld who is both high and low.

And *Brihadaranyaka Upanishad* IV. iv. 23 says:

> This is the eternal glory of a knower of Brahman: it never increases or decreases by work. [Therefore] one should know the nature of that alone. Knowing it one is not touched by evil action. Therefore he who knows it as such becomes self-controlled, calm, withdrawn into himself, enduring and concentrated, and sees the Self in his own body; he sees all as the Self. Evil does not overtake him, but he transcends all evil. Evil does not trouble him, [but] he consumes all evil. He becomes sinless, taintless, free from doubts, and a knower of Brahman.

Finally Sankara's commentary of *Gita* verse 4.37 says that (Swami Gambhirananda translator):

> ...the fire of Knowledge itself cannot directly burn actions to ashes, like pieces of wood. So, the idea implies is that full enlightenment is the cause of making all actions impotent.
>
> From the force of the context it follows that, since the result of actions owing to which the present body has been born has already become effective, therefore it gets exhausted only through experience it. Hence, Knowledge reduces to ashes only those actions what were done (in this life) prior to the rise of Knowledge and that have not become effective, as also those performed along with (i.e. after the dawn of) Knowledge, and those that were done in the many past lives.

It should be noted that those actions that have "already become effective" are not experienced like others who are not enlightened. Being fully enlightened, the remaining actions referred to appear as real as a mirage in the desert, the Reality to the enlightened soul being Brahman.

Comment: What does Adi Shankaracharya mean by "the fire of Knowledge itself cannot directly burn actions to ashes, like pieces of wood"?  In the rest of the passage he's talking about the fire of knowledge burning actions.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan It is a fine point in the Advaita. You cannot 'become' free (become Brahman) because you are free (Brahman) already - you only have to realize it. If you were not already the omnipotent omnipresent Brahman already you could never become the omnipotent omnipresent Brahman. You can not become something which you are not. The purification of the heart - fire - is like tearing away the veil of Maya, when the veil is removed, THAT which was there already is revealed. When THAT is revealed, the actions (karma) become impotent. There is no karma attached to THAT.

Comment: Knowledge is a relative term. It relates to action between a subject and an object and is experienced as " I cognise this"..Knowledge cannot exist in isolation.

Comment: @Krishna Knowledge with a capital K stands for Self-Realization of Brahman - direct Knowledge or experience of Brahman in the English translations and commentaries, it is fairly standardized. knowledge with a small k is the type of knowledge you refer to. Translators are consistent in the use of the small k and capital K in their translations.

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda - Well, sir, you seem to oblivious to the fact, that I have used capital "K" in my comment to refer to the Knowledge. Knowledge (capital K) is relative term. Whether it is capital K or small k, doesn't matter, Knowledge cannot exist in isolation.

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda - Here is the english transliteration of actual sanskrit text - "asti tavat sarvasiddhantinaam idamaham vedmiti karma-kartr-ghatita- kriya-visesa-abhasaha".  English translation " Knowledge (With capital K) is an awareness of the particular action that pertains to a subject and an object and is in the form of "I cognise this" ". Thus it is two way relational. Hope it helps

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda - OK, you were trying to say Vyavaharika and paramarthika levels. I for a moment forgot that you follow advaitam, hence your differentiation as "K" and "k". If that is the case, it is not possible to prove the existence of such an absolute knowledge bereft of " subject-object" relation.

Comment: @Krishna There is no proof in this material world for any concept of God, dualist or advaitist. Without direct realization, scripture says the proof is in scripture alone. Arguments and beliefs count for nothing, what counts is realization alone.

Comment: @Krishna the actual verse in Gita 4.37 uses the word 'jnanagnih'; which translates as 'the fire of Knowledge'

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda - Scripture is a pramana every vedantin accepts. No one is disputing it